# bash templating

Tags: bash, sed

i have a template, with a var LINK
and a data file, links.txt, with one url per line

how in bash i can substitute LINK with the content of links.txt?

if i do

```
#!/bin/bash
LINKS=$(cat links.txt)
sed "s/LINKS/$LINK/g" template.xml
```

two problem:

1. $LINKS has the content of links.txt without newline
2. sed: 1: "s/LINKS/http://test ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

sed is not escaping the // in the links.txt file

thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of what your links.txt and template.xml files look like?

Answer (score 2):

Use some better language instead. I'd write a solution for bash + awk... but that's simply too much effort to go into. (See http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile if you really want to do that)

Just use any language where you don't have to mix control and content text. For example in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
links = open('links.txt').read()
template = open('template.xml').read()
print template.replace('LINKS', links)
```

Watch out if you're trying to force sed solution with some other separator - you'll get into the same problems unless you find something disallowed in urls (but are you verifying that?) If you don't, you already have another problem - links can contain `<` and `>` and break your xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `ed`:

```
ed template.xml <<EOF
/LINKS/d
.r links.txt
w output.txt
EOF
```

- The first command will go to the line
  containing LINKS and delete it.
- The second line will insert the
  contents of links.txt on the current
  line.
- The third command will write the file
  to output.txt (if you omit output.txt
  the edits will be saved to
  template.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sed` twice.  On the first run, replace `/` with `\/`.  The second run will be the same as what you currently have.

Comment: This is unnecessary. You do not have to use the / character to in substitutions. You can use any character you want, so pick one that wont conflict with a URL. e.g. s|a|b| or s$a$b$ etc. (Note: I don't know if | or $ are invalid URL chars - I'm just using them as examples of characters different to /)

Comment: @camh- Good point. The `$` character is a valid URL character, so I would go with `|` or `^`.

Answer (score 0):

The character following the 's' in the sed command ends up the separator, so you'll want to use a character that is not present in the value of `$LINK`. For example, you could try a comma:

```
sed "s,LINKS,${LINK}\n,g" template.xml
```

Note that I also added a `\n` to add an additional newline.

Another option is to escape the forward slashes in $LINK, possibly using sed. If you don't have guarantees about the characters in $LINK, this may be safer.